# NPM IOS emulator unable to get application path

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm busy on an angular/nativescript project but I can't get the application running on the iOS emulator. The build itself is successful but the deployment fails.

```
Unable to apply changes on device: B1F01CA0-AEC5-452A-9D85-957B8BC398E3. Error is: Unable to get application path on device..
```

The above error is coming up whenever I want to send the build to the emulator.

I can't get find any related error to this error.
The stacktrace is as follows (I left out some path parts that aren't required)

```
=== BUILD TARGET nativescript OF PROJECT nativescript WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
while processing while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
/nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/28BJBFDGVGZZ3/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm: No such file or directory
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2DKXPQ92SAISO/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/28BJBFDGVGZZ3/Darwin-38I6DLZ5IH61J.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: while processing /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2DKXPQ92SAISO/Darwin-38I6DLZ5IH61J.pcm /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o): :
No such file or directorywarning:
/Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/28BJBFDGVGZZ3/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o)while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
:
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2DKXPQ92SAISO/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm: No such file or directorywarning:
/Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/28BJBFDGVGZZ3/Dispatch-2LX9MWM6UEPQW.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: while processing /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2DKXPQ92SAISO/Dispatch-2LX9MWM6UEPQW.pcm /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o): :
No such file or directorywarning:
/Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/28BJBFDGVGZZ3/ObjectiveC-1RQA2RIXJIE19.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2DKXPQ92SAISO/ObjectiveC-1RQA2RIXJIE19.pcm: No such file or directory
Project successfully built.
```

What setting/config do I need to look at? I cant find any difference in the variables from when I set it up the first time and got it working.

Answer (score 3):

I got it fixed, the solution was most likely as follows:

Start the emulator -> In the statusbar go to Hardware -> "Erase all content and Settings..." -> Press the power button on the emulator skin to restart

Comment: Oh man! I've been facing the exact same issue since last night and was desperate to solve it! I even opened an issue on ns github! You saved my ahss man! :D

Comment: didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I solved it as I explain in the picture.

I'm not sure it works for all iOS versions. In my app my iOS is V5.0.0 (iPhone 5) and my NativeScript is version 5v.

Show the first three steps in my picture:

[image]

4. Once you have crushed the state of emulation.
5. Exit and close the emulator.
6. Restart the command: $ tns run ios

Normally the phone will completely reset itself to reinstall the application.